# ListLinePlot showing the wrong domain and not starting at zero

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am trying to plot a graph that starts at zero from a list using `ListLinePlot`.

The code:

```
Data = Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}]
ListLinePlot[{Data, Data}]
```

[image]

The straight line should be starting at x = 0 and ending at x = 1. I have tried using `ListPlot`, but the same result is generated. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Missing `Transpose`. `Data = Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}];
ListLinePlot[Transpose@{Data, Data}]`

Comment: `ListLinePlot[Data, DataRange -> {0, 1}]`

Answer (score 2):

I assume OP wants to specify data in the form `{{x1,y1},...,{xn,yn}}` but `{Data,Data}` does not have that form:

```
{Data,Data}
(* {{0.,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.},{0.,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.}} *)
```

One can get the desired form using `Transpose`:

```
Transpose[{Data,Data}]
(* {{0.,0.},{0.1,0.1},{0.2,0.2},{0.3,0.3},{0.4,0.4},{0.5,0.5},{0.6,0.6},{0.7,0.7},{0.8,0.8},{0.9,0.9},{1.,1.}} *)
```

Therefore, OP should use

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{Data,Data}]]
```